# SQL query for top 3 results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've set of pages and each page has `PageID` and will record unique visitors information `IP`  , `Country` , `Browser` , `System` and `Date` of visit

Here is sample of the database table

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| PageID |     IP     | Country |  Browser | System  |   Date     | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1   | 00-00-00-1 |   UK    |  Chrome  |   Win7  | 2016-05-22 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|    6   | 00-00-00-2 |  France | Firefox  |   Win8  | 2016-05-25 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1   | 00-00-00-3 |   USA   | Firefox  |  WinXP  | 2016-05-26 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|    8   | 00-00-00-4 |  Spain  |   Opera  | Android | 2016-05-28 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1   | 00-00-00-5 |    UK   |  Chrome  |  Win10  | 2016-06-01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|    8   | 00-00-00-6 |  Italy  |  Safari  |Kardishan| 2016-06-02 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|    5   | 00-00-00-7 |   USA   | Unknown  | Android | 2016-06-02 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|    3   | 00-00-00-8 |    UK   |  Firefox |   Win7  | 2016-06-02 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My questions

1) How to make query to get top 3 countries where visitors comes from ? from the above sample the results should be :-

```
UK        3
USA       2
France    1
```

2) How to same query to get top 3 countries where visitors comes from where `PageID = 1` from the above sample the results should be :-

```
UK    2
USA   1
```

~ that would helps me a lot to understand how statics can be generated, thanks

Comment: This is basic SQL. What have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would give you the top `3` countries overall:

```sql
SELECT Country, COUNT(*)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Country 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 3
```

To get the top `3` for a specific `PageID` just add a `WHERE PageID = 1` clause.

Comment: Nah! should let them figure out the answers of questions like this by themselves. So they can learn how to implement and will not rely on others in the future

Comment: Thanks a lot, never knew that i can `ORDER BY COUNT(*)` ! this is brilliant and will helps me a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Country, COUNT(*) AS Visits
FROM <your_table_name>
GROUP BY Country
ORDER BY Visits;
```

This will get all countries along with the number of visits from the desired country in a descending order. Depending on your type of usage you may also add `LIMIT 3` to only get the top 3.

To only get visits to page with ID 1 you can use this similar query:

```
SELECT Country, COUNT(*) AS Visits
FROM <your_table_name>
WHERE pageID=1
GROUP BY Country
ORDER BY Visits;
```